# Marketing cloud "Cloudpage" as a standalone sign-up page

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, cloudpage

**Newbie to Salesforce Marketing Cloud:**

I have a requirement to develop a cloudpage as a stand-alone webpage which would collect new user data (sign-up page) and push them into Marketing cloud data extensions. Also, a welcome email has to be sent once the user hits "submit" button. My questions are:

1) Is it even possible to build a cloud page as a standalone webpage without redirecting from an email (not a landing page scenario from an email)?
2) Is it possible to use a "Triggered send" for welcome email without a "SubscriberKey"?

Appreciate any sort of inputs here.

Thanks,
Chandu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No.

It's a common use case for Cloud Pages to build Lead signup pages as you've described. Sending an Email without having a unique ID defined is doable by defining the Email Address as the identifier for that particular subscriber.

However you need to understand that there needs to exist a 1-to-1 link between your Contact and the `AllSubscribers` table, meaning if you don't have an ID for your Contact, the Email Address needs be marked as such in order to send Emails.

You'll be utilizing AMPscript [**InsertData**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm) or [**UpsertData**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) (depending on your exact requirements) to push data from the Cloud Page to your target Data Extension, commonly done via regular HTML [**POST**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) function.

Generally you would start out by creating a HTML form on your 'Welcome Page' to collect field inputs and *post*ing the form to your 'Thank You' page which holds the short AMPscript snippet to process the user inputted data to the Data Extension.

**Example Welcome Page**

```
<html>
    <form id="myNewForm" method="post" action="yourThankYouPageURL">
      First Name  <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
      Last Name  <input type="text" name="LastName"/>
      Email   <input type="text" name="Email" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

**Example Thank You Page**

```
%%[ 
    set @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
    set @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
    set @Email = RequestParameter("Email")
    InsertData("Your Data Extension","FirstName",@FirstName,"LastName",@LastName,"Email",@Email)
]%%

Thank You ~
```

This setup requires you to have a Data Extension with these 3 fields.

There is an slightly easier, UI-based way to set it up by using [**Cloud Pages SmartCapture**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture.htm&type=5) form that does the heavy lifting for you.

When you finally have some data in your Data Extension, then you can either use [**Automation Studio**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) (easy), [**Journey Builder**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) (easy) or [**Triggered Sends**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_triggered_emails.htm&type=5) (complex) to send the Email to your fresh lead. Although you will always need to use some field as the `SubscriberKey` in order to send an Email.

If your instance comes with Journey Builder, then the easiest and most efficient way would be to utilize it. There is even a specific Entry Source created just for [**new CloudPage submissions**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_cloudpages_to_admit_contacts.htm&type=5) which will work ideally in your use case.